# Rails4 app works with SQL server 2008?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does Ruby on Rails4 app works with MS SQL server 2008? It seems the gem everyone recomend to use - activerecord-sqlserver-adapter doesn't support rails 4.0.0 - https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/250

Comment: Yes there is no support for active record adapter for rails 4. But if you are ready to use Raw SQL queries then you can use TinyTds Gem - https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds.

Answer (score 0):

Until now Active Record 4 is not supported by sqlserver-adapter.
[Check here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver)